# Two forms of bases of the topology space generated by semi-norms

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras

Suppose $X$ is a vector space and $\mathcal{P}$ a family of seimorms on $X$. Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the topology on $X$ that has as a subbase the sets $\{x: p(x-x_0)<\varepsilon\}$. So the base of $X$ has the form
$$\cap_{j=1}^n\{x\in X: p_j(x-x_0)<\varepsilon_j\}.$$

This statment is from Page 99 of the book "A Course in Functional Analysis" by J.B. Conway.  However, this form of the base is different from which is in the book "Fundamentals of the theory of operator algebras" of R.V. Kadison. In Page 17 of Kadison's book, the Theorem 1.2.6 introduced the form of base of $X$ is
$$\{x\in X: p_j(x-x_0)<\varepsilon~(j=1,...,m)\}.$$

In Conway's book there are n $\varepsilon_j$ and, in Kadison's book, there is only one $\varepsilon$. Are these two forms same?

Comment: You can just take the minimum of the $\varepsilon_j$.

Comment: @Jochen I think if we take the minimum, the intersection will change.

Comment: You get indeed two different bases (the one with a single $\varepsilon$ has less sets) but every set of the basis with different $\varepsilon_j$ contains a member of the  other one. In particular, both bases give the same locally convex topology.